# Differential equation $uu''-u'^2=u'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this:
$$uu''-u'^2=u'$$
$$u'=\frac{du}{dx}$$

I can't solve it. I've done the recommended substitution $u'=v(u)$, so I have:
$$u''=v'=dv/dx=\frac{dv}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{du}u'$$
Substituting that in the initial equation I get 
$$u\frac{dv}{du}=v+1$$ 
So: $v=uc-1$
I don't know how to go on o get $u(x)$

EDIT: I've done this:
$$u'(x)=v(u)$$
$$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{du'}{du}=0$$
That last step is where I have doubts.
$$uu''-u'^2=u'\Longrightarrow uu'\frac{dv}{du}-u'^2=u'\Longrightarrow-u'^2=u'$$
So $u(x)=-x+c,\;\;c\in\mathbb{R}$
I'm missing solutions, right?

Comment: I got $v=Ku-1$. Now you just continue with $du/dx=Ku-1$ and separate again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming everything you've done so far is correct...)

By definition, $v(u)=u'$, so all you have to do now is solve $u'(x)=cu(x)-1$. This equation is separable, so can be easily solved.

Comment: God I feel so stupid

Comment: @MyUserIsThis Don't be so hard on yourself! We all have these moments.

Comment: In fact, $u'=cu-1$, not $cu+1$.

Comment: @did Yes, that was a typo, it was fine in my paper. Thanks.

Comment: @did: The question was edited since my reply; I just copied what I saw, with $u'$ substituted for $v$. Edited.